# How to store datetime on server side in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, express, mongoose

My users could create some objects that have specific time and search them by query for specific startTime and endTime.

My question is how should I store these objects in my database (MongoDB)? Should I store them in UTC or with specific timezone that relates to user that create object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use UTC date format, and convert all data to UTC: when create, update, delete objects or filter them. Use one UTC time zone helps you avoid a lot of problems, and simplify you code.

### example

```
> var now = new Date();
> Mon May 26 2014 10:55:34 GMT+0300 (Kaliningrad Standard Time)

> now.toUTCString();
> Mon, 26 May 2014 07:55:34 GMT

> new Date(now.toUTCString())
> Mon May 26 2014 10:55:34 GMT+0300 (Kaliningrad Standard Time)
```

Comment: So, should I know user's timezone in this case?

Comment: And which format should I use for storing in MongoDB?

Comment: No, just use one time zone for server side code. But if you need show date on front end, convert all dates to client time zone.

Comment: What will happen if the server time is wrong. It will always get the server time right. So how can I avoid to getting wrong time in nodejs and mongo

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new Javascript date object and assign it to a Mongo date field, it will automatically be usable with any timezone. If all you need is the current time, you can just use `new Date()`. But if you need to take a string and have it be interpreted in a specific timezone, or you are going to be presenting a time to a user in a specific timezone, I highly recommend checking out [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

This code will take a date object stored in a Mongo model (which could be 1AM on January 1, 2014 in Sydney, Australia) and present it formatted to a Los Angeles timezone (which would still be December 31, 2013).

```
collection.find({_id: 123}, function(err, model) {
    userDate = moment(model.date).tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
});
```

And if you ever need to parse a string that doesn't specify a UTC offset as a specific timezone, you can use the constructor:

```
moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto")
```